# find the differential equations (first order), through 2 particular solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the inhomogeneous first order differential equation below:

$\dot{x}(t)+ax(t)=q(t)$

where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $q(t)$ is a continuous function.

It is given that the differential equation has the following $2$ particular solutions:

\begin{align*}
x_1(t)&=e^{4t}+3e^{9t}\\
x_2(t)&=−e^{4t}+3e^{9t}
\end{align*}

> State below the value of the constant $a$ and an expression for the function $q(t).$

When I apply the solution formula, I get $1$ equation with $2$ different unknowns. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $\pm 1$ both work as constants multiplying the $e^{4t}$ term, that must correspond to the homogeneous solution $Ce^{4t},$ which implies $a=-4.$ (This is because arbitrary constants always arise from the homogeneous solution, never the particular solution.) The DE must now be
$$\dot{x}(t)-4x(t)=q(t). $$
Next, we suppose that $x(t)=e^{4t}+3e^{9t},$ and compute $\dot{x}(t)-4x(t):$
\begin{align*}
\dot{x}(t)-4x(t)
&=4e^{4t}+27e^{9t}-4\big(e^{4t}+3e^{9t}\big)\\
&=15e^{9t}\\
&=q(t).
\end{align*}